# Adding page numbers to pdf using iTextSharp on second pass is not working

Tags: itext, edit

So as the title says I am trying to add page numbers to an existing pdf document, I have researched this problem and come up with a few tutorials/examples.

[Here is the simplest example i can find](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/iTextSharp-Add-Page-numbers-to-existing-PDF-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx)

My code Compiles and runs successfully however the changes are not reflected in the pdf

my code

            `byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + ".pdf");`

```
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(bytes);

        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream()) 
        {

            using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms,'\0',true))
            {
                int n = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
                for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
                {

                    creatPageCountFooter(i + 1, n).WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 34, 803, stamper.GetOverContent(i));

                    //ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(stamper.GetUnderContent(i), Element.ALIGN_RIGHT, new Phrase(i.ToString(), blackFont), 568f, 15f, 0);

                }
                ms.ToArray();
            }
            pdfReader.Close();
        }
        File.WriteAllBytes(filePath + ".pdf", bytes);
```

the function "creatPageCountFooter"

`/**
     * Create a header table with page X of Y
     * @param count the page number
     * @param Total the total number of pages
     * @return a table that can be used as header
     */
    protected PdfPTable creatPageCountFooter(int count,int Total)
    {
        PdfPTable pageCount = new PdfPTable(3);
        pageCount.TotalWidth=250;`

```
    BaseFont bfTimes = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_ROMAN, BaseFont.CP1252, false);
    iTextSharp.text.Font times = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfTimes, 6);

    PdfPCell Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMM yyyy"), times));
    Cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
    Cell.Border = 0;
    pageCount.AddCell(Cell);

    Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(count.ToString() +" / "+ Total.ToString(), times));
    Cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    Cell.Border = 0;
    pageCount.AddCell(Cell);

    Cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Company name " + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy"), times));
    Cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
    Cell.Border = 0;
    pageCount.AddCell(Cell);

    return pageCount;

}
```

As a further note I have checked that this code actually runs and I have tried writing the file over the existing document or creating a new document and both times the changes don't reflect.

I will provide further details if required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code writes the `byte[] bytes` to a file:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(filePath + ".pdf", bytes);
```

But the only code in which that variable is set, is the initial

```
byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + ".pdf");
```

Thus, it is not surprising that *the changes are not reflected in the pdf* result file because you simply write the original bytes unchanged.

---

I assume you meant to set `bytes` to the contents of the memory stream in this line

```
ms.ToArray();
```

but forgot the `bytes =`. Unfortunately, though, that array retrieval call happens too early, it is still inside the `using PdfStamper` block:

```
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms,'\0',true))
{
    ...
    ms.ToArray();
}
```

Just like in the sample you refer to, the array has to be retrieved outside that `using` block, so that it is retrieved after the `PdfStamper` implicitly gets closed during disposal. Thus:

```
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, ms,'\0',true))
{
    ...
}
bytes = ms.ToArray();
```

Comment: doh. I can't believe I missed something so obvious. Thank you for your speedy assistance it is much appreciated.